# Permission denied when saving HTML on sublime text 3.1.1

Tags: html, git, sublimetext3

Try to save a basic HTML on Sublime Text 3.1.1, but the permission is denied. Because of Git packages, I'm looking into Preferences/Package Control.My Sublime was shaped for Git (packages) when I learned RoR. I have red ([How to solve Permission Denied when running Sublime Text 3 from the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892381/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-running-sublime-text-3-from-the-terminal)) that it probably comes from this packages. The issue is : can't remove packages linked to Git. any ideas ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The community will be better able to help you if you provide more info.

Are you on Windows or Mac OSX? What version of Sublime are you running? Are you able to save any files at all? Are you running sublime from the terminal like the author of the question you reference, or are you starting it normally?

What do you mean, specifically, that you can't remove packages linked to Git? Does your project require them, so you don't *want* to remove them, or are you getting an error when you try to remove them?

Comment: Hello, want to precise that I use a Mac Book Pro running OS High Sierra 10.13.6. Sublime Text3  3.1.1. I go to Preferences/Package Control. There, I browse and look for some packages. No All Autocomplete, Emmet, Git, and GitGutter. If someone knows about it, that would be great.